# split and join strings

Tags: python

I get my data in python iterator where each line is a char separated by `"\t"`.

 I can create this like :

```
iter1 = []
str = ""
for j in range (0,3):
    for i in range(0,9):
        str += "1\t"
    str += "1"
    iter1.append(str)
    str = ""
```

iter1 is looking like:

```
['1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1', '1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1', '1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1']
```

Now, i want to join this iterator by `"\n"`, but I also want that each `"\t"` will become `"\n"` so the final result would be :

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

After joining the iterator lines.

How can I do it in the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get tab-separated values in a list and want to convert all tabs to new-lines:

```
iter1 = ['\t'.join('1'*10) for _ in range(3)]

result = '\n'.join(iter1).replace('\t', '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> iter1 = ['1\t1\t1\t1\t1',
             '1\t1\t1\t1\t1',
             '1\t1\t1\t1\t1']
>>> s = '\n'.join([char for line in iter1
                   for char in line.split('\t')])

>>> print s
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```